# how can carry a statement a parameter

Tags: bison

I'm trying to write a Forth-like language. The secondary declaration works well, but I have trouble to use it.
While in "offical" Forth secondary is a list of addresses of primitives, in my approach a secondary is a bunch of calls, not only addresses. e.g. a declared MYFUNCTION in memory looks like this:

```
MYFUNCTION:
    call primitive_foo;
    call primitive_bar;
    ....
    call primitive_foobar;
    return ;
```

Statements are declared as follows:

```
stmt:
    VARIABLE '=' expr                         { $$ = opr('=', 2, $3, id($1)); }
    | PORT '=' expr                           { $$ = opr('=', 2, $3, id($1)); }
 ...
 ...
    | SECONDARY                               { $$ = opr(SECONDARY, 1, ??? ); }
```

The virtual ambiguity of SECONDARY statement is resolved by my lexical parser. The operator code is passed in order as SECONDARY due to parser recognises MYFUCTION as a secondary from symbol table declared "on the fly" and supplies the proper address of it.

But how can I pass this parameter to opr() function used in stmt declaration?

Perhaps I ought to modify my nodeType, but I'd avoid it.
Is there any workaround idea how can I pass that address?

Answer (score 1):

The lexer recognizes the token `SECONDARY` and needs to return something for the parser to use (the address of `MYFUNCTION`?) -- it should store it into `yylval`, and then the parser can use `$1` to get it.  You'll likely need an appropriate `%token<type> SECONDARY` declaration in your parser to make it work right.

The details of all this depend heavily on the details of the data structures you are using (which you don't describe) and your `%union` declaration.

Comment: This is the answer I was afraid of... :) but thanks.